# Intercept Json response and do some thing with my object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is that I want to convert my server timezone date time values from UTC to UserPreferred timezone such as PST.

When I am returning any object via Json, I will parse for the object's properties, and check to see if any properties are of type, DateTime, if so.. I will get the content of DateTime property, convert it from UTC to PST and return the data back to the user for Json response. I want to be able to do it for all the Json responses through out my application.

Here is my JsonResult controller method..

```
public JsonResult MyTestJsonB()
{
    var myTestModel = new TestModel
        {
            LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
            LastModifiedNullable = DateTime.UtcNow,
            TheStrinDateTime = "hello"
        };

    return Json(myTestModel, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When the above method is called or any where in my application when I do a "return Json(...) , I want to intercept this call, via reflection go through myTestModel or the passed in model object, and change some thing inside it.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think it might be worth describing the problem that you are trying to solve rather than the solution you believe will solve it. At the moment, I can't really make head or tail of this.

Comment: Yeah it definitely sounds like you're asking for a solution to a solution instead of a solution to a problem here.

Comment: Just provided the overall problem description. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Side note: it is generally easier to convert from Utc to local on client, than from on local (to PST/PDT) to another... So consider just sending Utc (possibly naming your fields explicitly).